# Unable to resolve dependency tree with eslint-config-airbnb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

when I'm trying to install eslint-config-airbnb with `npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb` I'm getting following error (--legacy-peer-deps flag doesn't help):

````
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: favnote@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb@"18.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (eslint-plugin-import, eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y, eslint-plugin-react)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.0.0    
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-react-hooks
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-react-hooks@"4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-react-hooks@"^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb@"18.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! ```
````

Comment: Can you show your package.json (or at least the dependencies and devDependencies) and also indicate what version of `npx` you are using?

Comment: @Trott sure, I'm sorry - 
package.json:

https://pastebin.com/SD5CxRQA

Comment: Thanks. And what's the output of `npx --version`?

Comment: $ npx --version
7.0.8

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and they will install successfully.

Looking at your `package.json` and comparing it to the peer dependencies listed for `eslint-config-airbnb`, you already have all the peer dependencies in your `package.json` as dev dependencies. (They were probably added there when you ran the `npx install-peerdeps` command but then that command tried to run `npm install` and failed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try locking in a specific working Node version by using `nvm` to roll Node back a few versions.

I rolled back from `v16.15` to `v16.13` and that seemed to fix the issue locally so I locked in that version with `node -v > .nvmrc` so that my hosting on Netlify/Vercel will use the version I specified.